# Adding an OLE-object to a property fails with "Win32::OLE(0.1709) error 0x80020003: in PROPERTYPUTREF"

Tags: excel, perl, win32ole

The following script works as intended.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

use Win32::Ole;
use Win32::OLE::Const 'Microsoft.Excel';

$Win32::OLE::Warn = 3;

my $excel = CreateObject Win32::OLE 'Excel.Application' or die;
$excel->{'Visible'} = 1;

my $workbook = $excel -> workbooks -> add(1);
my $sheet    = $workbook -> sheets(1);
my $shape    = $sheet    -> shapes -> addChart;
my $chart    = $shape    -> chart;

$chart -> {chartType} = xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers;

$sheet -> cells(1,1) -> {value} = "x";
$sheet -> cells(1,2) -> {value} = "sin(x)";

my $row = 1;
for my $x (map {$_ / 10} (0..100)) {
  $row ++;
  $sheet -> cells($row, 1) ->{value} =     $x;
  $sheet -> cells($row, 2) ->{value} = sin($x);
}

$chart -> setSourceData(
             $sheet->range(
               $sheet->cells(1,2),
               $sheet->cells(100,2)));

# This line works:
$chart -> SeriesCollection(1) -> {XValues} = '=Sheet1!$A$2:$A$102';

# Following doesn't work, fails with 
#   Win32::OLE(0.1709) error 0x80020003:
#     in PROPERTYPUTREF "XValues"
#
# $chart -> SeriesCollection(1) -> {XValues} = 
#    $sheet->Range(
#      $sheet->cells(2, 1   ),
#      $sheet->cells(2, $row)
#    );

$workbook -> {saved} = 1;
```

But if I change the line

```
$chart -> SeriesCollection(1) -> {XValues} = '=Sheet1!$A$2:$A$102';
```

with

```
  $chart -> SeriesCollection(1) -> {XValues} = 
   $sheet->Range(
     $sheet->cells(2, 1   ),
     $sheet->cells(2, $row)
   );
```

the script fails with the error message `Win32::OLE(0.1709) error 0x80020003: Member not found in PROPERTYPUTREF "XValues" at ...`.

IMHO, it should be possible to assign an OLE-Object to an OLE-Property (and I previously have already done this, albeit not to the `XValues` property).